# Call on specific item in XML through flash

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

I want to know how you would call on a specific item in xml through flash?
Here is my XML

```
<menu>
<day>
    <monday>            
        <maindish>
        <name>Curry Goat</name>
            <small>$6.86</small>
            <large>$9.00</large>
            </maindish>
    </monday>
    <tuesday>            
        <maindish>
        <name>Curry Goat</name>
            <small>$6.86</small>
            <large>$9.00</large>
            </maindish>
    </tuesday>
    <wednesday>            
        <maindish>
        <name>Curry Goat</name>
            <small>$6.86</small>
            <large>$9.00</large>
            </maindish>
    </wednesday>
</day>
```

This is the Code in Flash

```
for each (var maindish:XML in myXML..maindish)
```

How would a load the information for a specific day, lets say if it wednesday was selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Is this what you are looking for?

 var menueXml:XML = <menu>  
 <day>      
 <monday>
 <maindish>         
 <name>Curry Goat</name>
 <small>$6.86</small>              
 <large>$9.00</large>
 </maindish>     
 </monday>      
 <tuesday>
 <maindish>
 <name>Curry Goat</name>
 <small>$6.86</small> 
 <large>$9.00</large>
 </maindish>      
 </tuesday>      
 <wednesday>
 <maindish>
 <name>Curry Goat</name>
 <small>$6.86</small>
 <large>$9.00</large> 
 </maindish>
 </wednesday>
 </day>
 </menu>;

 for each(var main in menueXml.day){
 trace(main.monday.maindish.name.text());
 trace(main.monday.maindish.small.text());
 trace(main.monday.maindish.large.text());
 trace(main.tuesday.maindish);
 trace(main.wednesday.maindish);
 }
```

Comment: kind of...i want a day to be selected and then flash will parse and display the data for that selected day.

Comment: is the way i organized my xml okay?

Comment: in Xml you can use monday, tuesday, wednesday, as the attribute of the day so your xml will look like this: <menu><day current="monday"><dish></dish><small></small><large></large></day> and can tell flash if Current day = monday then display maindish for monday.